# Adding class - syntax error identifer 'string'

Tags: c++-cli

Im trying to add new class to existing  project. My class work corectly when it was under System::Windows::Forms::Form class inside Windows Form Application Project. I want to add my class to that project because i want all classes in different files. But when i want to compile I got error "syntax error : identifier 'String'". When i delete String object everything can be compiled. Where's problem ?

```
#ifndef ConGen
#define ConGen

template <class T> 
ref class GenerateControls
{

public:
    GenerateControls(int i , int j, int k,int l, int m)//, String ^ n)//, int o, int p)
    : size(i),x(j),y(k),rozstawx(l),rozstawy(m), name(n), sizex(o), sizey(p)
    {
        tablica = gcnew array < T ^ >(size);

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < i ; ++j)
        {
            tablica[j] = gcnew T(); 
            tablica[j]->Name = String::Concat(n,Convert::ToString(j));
            tablica[j]->Location = System::Drawing::Point(x+rozstawx*j,y+rozstawy*j);
            //tablica[j]->Size = System::Drawing::Size(sizex,sizey);
            tablica[j]->AutoSize = true;
            tablica[j]->Visible = true;
        }

    }
    ~GenerateControls()
    {
        //for ( int j = 0 ; j < size ; ++ j )
        //{
        //}
    }


property int Size
{
    void set(int value)
    {
        //if(value < 0 ) throw
        size=value;
    }
    int get()
    {
        return size;
    }
}
property array< T ^ > ^ Tablica
{
    array<T ^ > ^ get()
    {
        return tablica;
    }
}

void SetVisible ( int i)
{
    for( int j = 0 ; j < size ; ++j)
    {
        if ( j < i ) tablica[j]->Visible = true;
        else tablica[j]->Visible = false;
    }

}

void SetPosition( int x, int y, int odleglosc_x, int odleglosc_y, int ile)
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i<ile ; ++i)
    {
        Tablica[i]->Location = System::Drawing::Point(x+odleglosc_x*i,y+odleglosc_y*i);
    }
}

private:
    array < T ^ > ^ tablica;
    int size;
    int x;
    int y;
    int rozstawx;
    int rozstawy;
    int sizex;
    int sizey;
//  String  ^ name;
};


#endif
```

---

I want to participate my code to few classes but something weird is happened. This is my Form class:

```
#pragma once
#include "ConGen.h"

namespace Trening {

        using namespace System;
        using namespace System::ComponentModel;
        using namespace System::Collections;
        using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
        using namespace System::Data;
        using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;
        using namespace System::Drawing;


        public ref class okno2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {
        public:
                okno2(void)
                {
                        InitializeComponent();
                }

        protected:

                ~okno2()
                {
                        if (components)
                        {
                                delete components;
                        }
                }

        private:

        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

        System::Windows::Forms::TabControl ^ tabcontrol;
        System::Windows::Forms::TabPage ^ tabpage1;
        System::Windows::Forms::TabPage ^ tabpage2;
        System::Windows::Forms::TabPage ^ tabpage3;

        System::Data::SqlClient::SqlConnection ^ sqlcon;

        GenerateControls < System::Windows::Forms::TextBox > ^ tb1;
        GenerateControls < System::Windows::Forms::TextBox > ^ tb2;
        GenerateControls < System::Windows::Forms::TextBox > ^ tb3;

        GenerateLabels < System::Windows::Forms::Label > ^ lb1;
        GenerateLabels < System::Windows::Forms::Label > ^ lb2;
        GenerateLabels < System::Windows::Forms::Label > ^ lb3;

        array < String ^ > ^ stringtabs1;
        array < String ^ > ^ stringtabs2;
        array < String ^ > ^ stringtabs3;

        array < String ^ > ^ textboxtabs1;
        array < String ^ > ^ textboxtabs2;
        array < String ^ > ^ textboxtabs3;

        int clientwidth;
        int clientheight;


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

                void InitializeComponent(void)
                {

                        clientwidth = 300;
                        clientheight = 300;

                        this->tabcontrol = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabControl();
                        this->tabpage1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage();
                        this->tabpage2 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage();
                        this->tabpage3 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage();

                        this->tabcontrol->SuspendLayout();
                        this->tabpage1->SuspendLayout();
                        this->tabpage2->SuspendLayout();
                        this->tabpage3->SuspendLayout();

                        // tabcontrol

                        this->tabcontrol->Alignment = System::Windows::Forms::TabAlignment::Top;
                        this->tabcontrol->Controls->Add(this->tabpage1);
                        this->tabcontrol->Controls->Add(this->tabpage2);
                        this->tabcontrol->Controls->Add(this->tabpage3);
                        this->tabcontrol->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
                        this->tabcontrol->HotTrack = true;
                        this->tabcontrol->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0,0);
                        this->tabcontrol->Multiline = true;
                        this->tabcontrol->Name = L"tabcontrol";
                        this->tabcontrol->SelectedIndex = 0;
                        this->tabcontrol->ShowToolTips = true;
                        this->tabcontrol->Size = System::Drawing::Size(215,129);
                        this->tabcontrol->TabIndex =1;

                        // tb1 & lb1

                        tb1 = gcnew GenerateControls< System::Windows::Forms::TextBox >(10,85,80,0,30,"tb1",145,35);
                        //lb1 = gcnew GenerateLabels< System::Windows::Forms::Label >(10,20,80,0,30,"lb1",35,20);     <----------------------------- TU
                        // tabPage1

                        this->tabpage1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PaleGreen;
                        this->tabpage1->Controls->AddRange(tb1->Tablica);
                        //this->tabpage1->Controls->AddRange(lb1->Tablica);
                        this->tabpage1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(4, 4);
                        this->tabpage1->Name = L"tabpage1";
                        this->tabpage1->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(3);
                        this->tabpage1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(207, 103);
                        this->tabpage1->TabIndex = 0;
                        this->tabpage1->Text = L"Dane";
                        this->tabpage1->ToolTipText = L"Informacje o użytkowniku";
                        this->tabpage1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

                        //tb2 & lb2

                        tb2 = gcnew GenerateControls< System::Windows::Forms::TextBox >(10,85,80,0,30,"tb1",145,35);
                        //lb2 = gcnew GenerateLabels< System::Windows::Forms::Label >(10,20,80,0,30,"lb1",35,20);     <----------------------------- TU

                        // tabPage2

                        this->tabpage2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Plum;
                        this->tabpage2->Controls->AddRange(tb2->Tablica);
                        //this->tabpage1->Controls->AddRange(lb2->Tablica);
                        this->tabpage2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(4, 4);
                        this->tabpage2->Name = L"tabpage2";
                        this->tabpage2->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(3);
                        this->tabpage2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(207, 103);
                        this->tabpage2->TabIndex = 1;
                        this->tabpage2->Text = L"Wymiary";
                        this->tabpage2->ToolTipText = L"Wymiary poszczególnych partii";
                        this->tabpage2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

                        //tb3 & lb3

                        tb3 = gcnew GenerateControls< System::Windows::Forms::TextBox >(10,85,80,0,30,"tb1",145,35);
                        //lb3 = gcnew GenerateLabels< System::Windows::Forms::Label >(10,20,80,0,30,"lb1",35,20);     <----------------------------- TU
                        // tabPage3

                        this->tabpage3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Plum;
                        this->tabpage3->Controls->AddRange(tb3->Tablica);
                        //this->tabpage1->Controls->AddRange(lb3->Tablica);
                        this->tabpage3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(4, 4);
                        this->tabpage3->Name = L"tabpage3";
                        this->tabpage3->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(3);
                        this->tabpage3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(207, 103);
                        this->tabpage3->TabIndex = 2;
                        this->tabpage3->Text = L"Osiągi";
                        this->tabpage3->ToolTipText = L"Twoje osiągi";
                        this->tabpage3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;


                        this->Controls->Add(this->tabcontrol);
                        this->tabcontrol->ResumeLayout(false);
                        this->tabpage1->ResumeLayout(false);
                        this->tabpage1->PerformLayout();
                        this->tabpage2->ResumeLayout(false);
                        this->tabpage2->PerformLayout();
                        this->tabpage3->ResumeLayout(false);
                        this->tabpage3->PerformLayout();

                        this->ResumeLayout(false);

                        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
                        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
                        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(clientwidth, clientheight);
                        this->Name = L"Form1";
                        this->Text = L"Form1";
                        this->ResumeLayout(false);
                }
#pragma endregion

                 }

        };
}
```

And this is class GenerateControls & GenerateLabels (there are in one file because when they are split i can't compile).

```
#ifndef ConGen
#define ConGen


using namespace System;
namespace Trening
{
        template <class T> 
        ref class GenerateControls
        {

        public:
                GenerateControls(int i , int j, int k,int l, int m, String ^ n, int o, int p)
                : size(i),x(j),y(k),rozstawx(l),rozstawy(m), name(n)//, sizex(o), sizey(p)
                {
                        tablica = gcnew array < T ^ >(size);

                        for ( int j = 0 ; j < i ; ++j)
                        {
                                tablica[j] = gcnew T();        
                                tablica[j]->Name = String::Concat(n,Convert::ToString(j));
                                tablica[j]->Location = System::Drawing::Point(x+rozstawx*j,y+rozstawy*j);
                                //tablica[j]->Size = System::Drawing::Size(sizex,sizey);
                                tablica[j]->AutoSize = true;
                                tablica[j]->Visible = true;
                        }

                }
                ~GenerateControls()
                {
                        //for ( int j = 0 ; j < size ; ++ j )
                        //{
                        //}
                }


        property int Size
        {
                void set(int value)
                {
                        //if(value < 0 ) throw
                        size=value;
                }
                int get()
                {
                        return size;
                }
        }
        property array< T ^ > ^ Tablica
        {
                array<T ^ > ^ get()
                {
                        return tablica;
                }
        }

        void SetVisible ( int i)
        {
                for( int j = 0 ; j < size ; ++j)
                {
                        if ( j < i ) tablica[j]->Visible = true;
                        else tablica[j]->Visible = false;
                }

        }

        void SetPosition( int x, int y, int odleglosc_x, int odleglosc_y, int ile)
        {
                for ( int i = 0 ; i<ile ; ++i)
                {
                        Tablica[i]->Location = System::Drawing::Point(x+odleglosc_x*i,y+odleglosc_y*i);
                }
        }

        void SetSize( int x, int y, int ile)
        {
                // if (ile > Size ) throw
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < ile ; ++i)
                {
                        Tablica[i]->Size = System::Drawing::Size(x, y);
                }
        }

        private:
                array < T ^ > ^ tablica;
                int size;
                int x;
                int y;
                int rozstawx;
                int rozstawy;
                int sizex;
                int sizey;
                String  ^ name;

        };

        #include "ConGen.h" // skopiowałem poprzez crtl + a całą klasę i zapomniałem usunąć tej linijki.
using namespace System;

template < class T >
        ref class GenerateLabels : public GenerateControls< T > //: public SetControlText< T >
        {
                public:

            GenerateLabels(int i , int j, int k,int l, int m, String ^ n, int o, int p)
                :GenerateControls( i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p)
                {
                }
                ~GenerateLabels()
                {
                }

                void SetText( array< String ^ > ^ name)
                {
                        int i = 0;
                        //if (name.Size != controlarray.Size ) throw 
                        for each ( String ^ str in name)
                        {
                                Tablica[i++]->Text = str;
                        }
                }

        };
}
#endif
```

With out code witch is marked "<--------Tu" i got error like these ( he is in first class okno2).

```
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: tablica): (0x04000033).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: size): (0x04000034).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: x): (0x04000035).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: y): (0x04000036).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: rozstawx): (0x04000037).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: rozstawy): (0x04000038).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: sizex): (0x04000039).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: sizey): (0x0400003a).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; fields: name): (0x0400003b).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>): (0x02000005).
1>Trening.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Inconsistent implemented interfaces in duplicated types (types: Trening.GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::Label>; interfaces: System.IDisposable): (0x09000002).
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors
```

I think something is wrong with GenerateLabels class. Because when instance of that class isn't inicializet i got that errors. With GenerateControls everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `using namespace System;` in your code. Did you trim that when copy/pasting to the web, or do you need to add it?

I see you're referencing System::Drawing::Point and System::Drawing::Size by their full namespaces, could be you just need the using directive for System::String.

Comment: Thank's i forgot use System namespace. But what "1>Trening.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000012) GenerateControls<System::Windows::Forms::TextBox>::set_Size" Mean ? I can't use normal library and I nead to use dll?

Comment: That sounds like your Trening class isn't able to see the Size property quite right (properties get turned into get_ and set_ methods behind the scenes). This may be related to the fact that you're using templates, consider switching to C#-style generics instead.

Comment: Everything is ok when I don't have that class in another file. So class is ok but something is wrong with adding that header file.